# CSS Transitions on tab load - bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am creating a home screen and I have 3 tabs that you can go between on the home screen. When you click one all the li's within the tab transition in to the page but if you click between the tabs quickly then they don't always load. This only seems to effect Chrome on pc and mac and sometimes safari on mac. Fine on firefox on pc and mac.

http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/1f7dbb81f464fb5b0e1a4f5bacc30a56

Tab JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav li').click(function(){
    $('nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-tab')).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Portion of css

```
.tab-content .tab li {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatey(-50px) scale(0);
}
.tab-content .tab.active li { 
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: translatey(0) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  .tab-content .tab.active li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    transition-delay: (#{$i * 0.1}s); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add vendor specific values for transform and transition properties. Below is the modified CSS:

```
  $headerColour: #456878; $headerHeight: 58px; $headerLineHeight: $headerHeight - 2px; @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900); .cf:after {
            clear: both;
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        body {
            background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/12596/bg.png");
            background-attachment: fixed;
            -ms-background-size: contain;
            background-size: contain;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: "Lato";
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 300;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        header {
            background: $headerColour;
            height: $headerHeight;
            position: relative;
        }

            header li {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                line-height: $headerLineHeight;
            }

                header li.logo {
                    left: 20px;
                }

                header li.user {
                    right: 20px;
                }

        .wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 120px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto;
            width: 80%;
        }

        nav {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

            nav li {
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
                cursor: pointer;
                float: left;
                font-size: 20px;
                margin-right: 60px;
                -webkit-transition: color 500ms ease 0s;
                -moz-transition: color 500ms ease 0s;
                -ms-transition: color 500ms ease 0s;
                -o-transition: color 500ms ease 0s;
                transition: color 500ms ease 0s;
                width: 100px;
            }

                nav li:not(.active):hover,
                nav li.active {
                    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
                }

                nav li.active {
                    font-size: 22px;
                    font-weight: 400;
                }

        .tab-content .tab {
            position: absolute;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

            .tab-content .tab.active {
                visibility: visible;
            }

            .tab-content .tab > ul {
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }

            .tab-content .tab li {
                background: #fff;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                float: left;
                background: #fff;
                margin: 20px;
                -ms-border-radius: 30px;
                border-radius: 30px;
                -ms-opacity: 0;
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transform: translatey(-50px) scale(0);
                -moz-transform: translatey(-50px) scale(0);
                -ms-transform: translatey(-50px) scale(0);
                -o-transform: translatey(-50px) scale(0);
                transform: translatey(-50px) scale(0);
            }

            .tab-content .tab.active li {
                -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
                -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
                -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
                -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
                transition: all 500ms ease;
                -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
                -moz-transform-origin: top center;
                -ms-transform-origin: top center;
                -o-transform-origin: top center;
                transform-origin: top center;
                -webkit-transform: translatey(0) scale(1);
                -moz-transform: translatey(0) scale(1);
                -ms-transform: translatey(0) scale(1);
                -o-transform: translatey(0) scale(1);
                transform: translatey(0) scale(1);
                -ms-opacity: 1;
                opacity: 1;
            }

        @for $i from 1 through 50 {
            .tab-content .tab.active li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                transition-delay: (#{$i * 0.1}s);
            }
        }
```

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gIDsv

Comment: That doesn't fix it. I am using prefix free plugin built into codepen